# How do I cleanly re-install samba after deleting some folders?

Tags: linux, fedora, samba, clean-install

I had samba installed on my fedora server and when it didn't work I tried to fix it by deleting the samba folder in /etc and reinstalling samba. Now after I install samba I can never get the service to start. The folder is never created in /etc. Please help me in completely removing samba and re-installing it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Samba the same way you installed it? `yum remove`

Comment: hello @uSlackr , actually I used dnf and yes I tried removing it. Also I tried:     'dnf autoremove' . it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you get an error when the uninstall ran?

Comment: hello @uSlackr , no I didn't. Actually what I had to do is remove all dependencies by: dnf remove samba*, some how this removed a lot of packages that weren't removed before. when I tried to reinstall afterwards I noticed the download size is much larger than before. So now it's working again.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove and install samba-common.